# Add a div into a flexbox nav so it appears over the content below instead of pushing it down

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a search box that can have a variable number of results. The growth of results is pushing down the elements below it. I'm trying to understand the best way to avoid this in the most maintainable way. I want the results to overlap whatever is beneath it, not grow the underlying container.

I was wondering if I make the results actually float, but it screwed up the whole layout and I'm trying to go with a flex-first approach.

#### Snippet:

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    nav {
      min-width: 800px;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
      column-gap: 40px;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .search-container {
      border: 2px solid darkgrey;
      border-radius: 20px;
      flex-basis: 40%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      column-gap: 20px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .search-container a, .search-container p {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b5b5;
      background-color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .search-container p {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 30px 20px;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    }

    .search-container a:last-child {
      border: none;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    }

    .links-container {
      display: flex;
      padding: 10px 0;
      flex-basis: 40%;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .links-container a {
      height: 60px;
      padding: 20px 40px;
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
    }

    .links-container a:hover {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .header-overlay {
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 800px;
      height: 120px;
      background-color: lightgrey;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
  <div class="header-overlay"></div>
    <nav>
      <div class="search-container">
        <p>Search Results</p>
        <a href="#">Result 1</a>
        <a href="#">Result 2</a>
        <a href="#">Result 3</a>
        <a href="#">Result 4</a>
        <a href="#">Result 5</a>
      </div>
      <div class="links-container">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
        <a href="#">Three</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

#### Desired Result:

[image]

Comment: You can separate the search box and result box. Use position absolute on the result box

Comment: @StacyJ Do you have an example? I still want my results to simulate effect that the box itself is growing (similar to google search box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To position an element over other elements, you use `position:absolute`. However - just like floats - this takes the element out of the flow and affects your flex nav.

Therefore to keep your search box as part of the flexbox display, you need an extra element to take the absolute position. Inside your `search-container`, add a container for the results that will have the absolute positioning.

The CSS for these 2 elements should be like this:

```
.search-container {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.search-results {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This keeps the search container as flex using 40% of the width, and the `search-results` div takes on the styling and flex display to make it work as you want it to.

By using `position:relative` for the search container div, we can place the results div relative to the search container, so we are able to position in inside it so it appears where it was, except overlaying the page.

**Working Example:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  min-width: 800px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 40px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.search-container {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.search-results {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.search-container a,
.search-container p {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b5b5;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-container p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.search-container a:last-child {
  border: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.links-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 0;
  flex-basis: 40%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.links-container a {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.links-container a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.header-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-overlay"></div>
    <nav>
      <div class="search-container">
        <div class="search-results">
          <p>Search Results</p>
          <a href="#">Result 1</a>
          <a href="#">Result 2</a>
          <a href="#">Result 3</a>
          <a href="#">Result 4</a>
          <a href="#">Result 5</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="links-container">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
        <a href="#">Three</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Page Heading</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Fluffy! This was intuitive for me. So basically just needed absolute to rip out of the document flow, but in order for it to still respect the position it was in, we made it position relative to it's parent (search-container) instead of the <nav> element, right?

Comment: @Ryan Yes, that's exactly it! The parent element still takes on the flex properties so it gets positioned correctly in your nav, and the child container is positioned with absolute values relative to the flex parent so we can place it inside it.

Answer (score 2):

Put the result links in a div and position it absolutely. It's parent container i.e the search container should be positioned relatively.

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    nav {
      min-width: 800px;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
      column-gap: 40px;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .search-container {
      border: 2px solid darkgrey;
      border-radius: 20px;
      flex-basis: 40%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      column-gap: 20px;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative
    }

    .search-container a, .search-container p {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b5b5;
      background-color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .search-container p {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 30px 20px;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    }

    .search-container a:last-child {
      border: none;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    }

    .result-box{
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     background: red;
    }
    .result-box a{
      display: block;
     }

    .links-container {
      display: flex;
      padding: 10px 0;
      flex-basis: 40%;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .links-container a {
      height: 60px;
      padding: 20px 40px;
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
    }

    .links-container a:hover {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .header-overlay {
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 800px;
      height: 120px;
      background-color: lightgrey;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
  <div class="header-overlay"></div>
    <nav>
      <div class="search-container">
        <p>Search Results</p>
        <div class="result-box">
        <a href="#">Result 1</a>
        <a href="#">Result 2</a>
        <a href="#">Result 3</a>
        <a href="#">Result 4</a>
        <a href="#">Result 5</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="links-container">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
        <a href="#">Three</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Stacy. The tricky thing here, is now you can tell that the results aren't part of the textbox (based on the border). I want it to look or be that the box grows, but doesn't affect the surrounding elements.

Comment: I've attached a goal image for what I'm working on in actuality

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it using position absolute. Refer @FluffyKitten's answer